# how to set base image after removing all image magento 2

Tags: product-images, magento-2.1.2

I have to set Base Image,Thumbnail and small image after removing all image programmatically.

I am trying this **code to remove all image from product**

```
$productRepository = $this->_objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface');
$product = $this->_objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($proPaint->getProductId());
$existingMediaGalleryEntries = $product->getMediaGalleryEntries();
foreach ($existingMediaGalleryEntries as $key => $entry) {
        unset($existingMediaGalleryEntries[$key]);
}
$product->setMediaGalleryEntries($existingMediaGalleryEntries);
$productRepository->save($product);
```

and this code for add image as **base,small** and **thumbnail**

```
$product->addImageToMediaGallery($imagePath, array('image','small_image','thumbnail','swatch_image'), false, false);
```

but it is not save as **base,small** or **thumbnail**

How can i **set base image small** and **thumbnail** after removing all image

Comment: Just for clarification, are you trying to set "custom placeholder images" to all your products?

Comment: Yes i am changing my product images when my custom attribute change

Comment: Aren't there already placeholder images by default in magento? Why dont just override them in the files?